# Quick question about $p$-primary component group

Tags: group-theory, notation, abelian-groups

For the following notation on $p$-primary groups:

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $p$ be a prime.
Let $G(p)=\{a\in G: |a|=p^n \text{ for some $n$}\geq 0 \}\tag1$  and
$G(p)=\{a\in G: p^na = 0 \text{ for some $n$}\geq 0 \}\tag2$

and consider the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be an abelian group and $a\in G$ an element of finite order.  Then $a=a_{1}+a_{2}+ \cdots+a_{t},$ with $a_{i}\in G(p_{i})$, where $p_{1},p_{2}, \ldots,p_{t}$ are the distinct positive primes that divide the order of $a$.

The beginning of the proof of the theorem goes as follows:

Proof:  The proof is by induction on the number of distinct primes that divide the order of $a$.  If $|a|$ is divisible only by the single prime $p_1$, then the order of $a$ isa  power of $p_1$ and, hence, $a\in G(p_1)$.  So the lemma is true in this case.  Assume inductively that the lemma is true for all elements whose order is divisible at most $k-1$ distinct primes and that $|a|$ is divisible by the distinct primes ${p_1}^{r_1}, \cdots, {p_k}^{r_k},$ with each $r_i>0.$...

I tried using the following example to understand the theorem with $G=Z_{12}$, and $G(2)=\{0,3,6,9\}$, and $G(3)=\{0,4,8\}$

so if I pick $8\in Z_{12}=G$, then $|8|=3$ from $(1)$, but $8(3)=24\equiv 0 \pmod {12}$ from $(2)$.  What I would like to know is what does it mean to say that the prime divisors of 8 in $Z_{12}$ is $3$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In this context, "the prime divisors of $8$ in $Z_{12}$" means nothing. What $3$ is, is the *order* of $8$ in $\Bbb Z_{12}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval the reason for my post is that the proof of the theorem, or the beginning of it goes as follows:  The proof is by induction on the number of distinct primes that divide the order of $a$.  If $|a|$ is divisible only by the single prime $p_1$, then the order of $a$ isa  power of $p_1$ and, hence, $a\in G(p_1)$.  So the lemma is true in this case.  Assume inductively that the lemma is true for all elements whose order is divisible at most $k-1$ distinct primes and that $|a|$ is divisible by the distinct primes ${p_1}^{r_1}, \cdots, {p_k}^{r_k},$ with each $r_i>0.$....

Comment: @AnneBauval hence I am a bit confused over when i look at the examples in the text and say in the case of 8, then |8|=3 in $Z_{12}$ but then $8\in G(3)$ and is also an element of $Z_{12}$.  So there must be something i don't understand in how the proof is discussing the $G(p_i)$ notation.  So when does the notation is referring to $|a|$ is divisible by the distinct primes, versus $|a|$ has order of ${p_i}^{r_i}$?

Comment: $|a|$ *is* the order of $a.$ It is the prime divisors of the natural number $|a|$ (not of the element $a$ of the group) which we look at. What confuses you in "$8\in G(3)\subset\Bbb Z_{12}$"? Are you comfortable with the equivalence between the two definitions (1) and (2) of $G(p)$?

Comment: @AnneBauval so in the example of my post, $|8|=3$ is the order of 8 and is the prime divisor of the natural number $|8|$.  Is that the correct translation?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Whereas for instance $|5|=12=2^2\cdot3$ and $5=9+8\pmod{12}$, $9\in G(2),8\in G(3).$

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you so very very much.  This is the second time you have helped me with my reading difficulties in math.

Comment: Use `**Theorem**` for **Theorem**.